# PWA successfully published on Google Play using TWA has an abnormal behave

Tags: android, google-play, progressive-web-apps, trusted-web-activity

We published our PWA on Google Play using Trusted Web Activities. App was successfully signed and released.

In order to successfully sign and publish the app, We strictly followed the step by step official tutorial at the following address:

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/02/using-twa

We used Android Studio.

The app on google play is:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.coelotec.meteodrome

The Android App locally installed on device, calls the following url that points to the web app (PWA):
https://app.meteodrome.it

The Web App, is a PWA developed with Angular 6.0.
Pre-rendering is not activated. Server return the classic bundle of javascripts, html and css.

However some of the users are reporting some issues, such as having two icons on their screen. One is named "MeteoDrome" and the other one "Meteo Drome" with the space. 
One of the icons contains the correct logo of the app. The other one has the default android logo. Clicking on the first one, app correctly loads. Clicking the default android logo named "Meteo Drome", browser loads showing the app. 
In the first case you correctly see the full screen app, in the second case you see the app wrapped in chrome. When you see chrome the address bar is visible.
Other users reports that they are not able to correctly load app. They usually see white screen instead of the right interface. Especially when the android version is old.

But for many other users app works fine and have no problems.
Many users in facts, neither see two icons on theirs screen nor loads a white screen view.

The app have got many likes and is much appreciated among the users. However it has also an unusual number of uninstalls.
Probably when the app works fine users doesn't uninstall.

We have no idea of what to do.

1) How can We understand what happen when the app is uninstalled and why is it uninstalled?

2) Besides, the users can:
 a - find two icons on the screen. 
 b - find the correct icon on the screen and the android logo in the app list.
 c - find only the right icon on the screen without seeing any other icons.
Why does this happen?

3) Why sometime some users report me that they see white screen even if their android version is good to install the app? And in other cases the app works fine?

We really have no idea of what to do and we have some serious problems with the abnormal percentage of uninstall.
Please, help us.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

1. Is possible that some users may have installed the application from the Play Store and also installed using the [Add to Home Screen](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/app-install-banners/)?
2. The Application available on the Play Store is being server with the default Android logo. The [Image Asset Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/image-asset-studio) inside Android Studio can help with creating new one.
3. Users with versions of Chrome < 72 or that have other browser as their default browsers will be shown the application in a Custom Tab as a fallback. This can be customised inside your application by implementing your own fallback method.

Finally, a good way to get started with your use case is to checkout the [sample application on Github](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/svgomg-twa). It is designed to be an easy option to get started with TWAs, and can be used as a starting point for your own app.

Comment: The sample application will fallback to use custom tabs, if the user's default browser supports it. Otherwise it will fallback to using regular browser Intents (eg: just open the page in the default browser). Would you have further details on devices / versions where the users are seeing the white screen?

Comment: We checked out the sample application. But is this sample app already implemented to fallback to use custom tabs, if the user's default browser supports it and to use regular browser Intents (eg: just open the page in the default browser) if not supported? Or we have to implement this logic by ourselves?What's the difference from the app we implemented by following the steps in official tutorial and this sample app?
Tutorial: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/02/using-twa